# Highcharts plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter gets called multiple times for same data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Requirement and strategy :**

I'm using Highcharts to create a 3d donut for one of my requirement. I have a requirement in which I need to add the percentage of all the values lesser than a year.

I'm using the `plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter` function of Highcharts to get the percentage and then do the total within the function.

**Code :**

Below is the code I'm using

```js
var usageInAYear = 0;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 300,
    type: 'pie',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 45,
      beta: 0
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'OUIWEBTEMPLATE'
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      depth: 35,
      innerSize: 50,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {

          if (this.point.name !== '> 1 year' && this.point.name !==
            'NOT USED') {
            usageInAYear += this.percentage;
          }
          console.log(this.percentage);
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0) +
            '%';
        },

      },
      showInLegend: true,
      colors: ['#50B432',
        '#F5B041',
        '#CB4335'
      ]
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser Usage',
    data: [{
      "name": "< 3 months",
      "y": 2004,
      "color": "#64E572"
    }, {
      "name": "3-6 months",
      "y": 18,
      "color": "#F2C60E"
    }, {
      "name": "6-12 months",
      "y": 30,
      "color": "#24CBE5"
    }, {
      "name": "> 1 year",
      "y": 136,
      "color": "#2A2383"
    }, {
      "name": "NOT USED",
      "y": 1111,
      "color": "#F44336"
    }]
  }]
});

document.getElementById("usage").innerHTML = Highcharts.numberFormat(usageInAYear, 0) + '%'
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<p>
  Usage in a year =
  <span id="usage"></span>
</p>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>

</figure>
```

**Problem Statement :**

Now the problem I'm facing is that the `formatter` function gets called multiple times for the same pie slice. Because of which same label percentage is added again and again to the final number.

If I remove the return statement from the `formatter` function, then it gets called only once, but then the percentage labels are not visible, which I need to show as part of the chart.

I know there are other ways to get the required result, but I am confused why this one is not working. Can anybody please help me. What is wrong here.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4tsndwm/) link having the same code.

Comment: i spend half our on this. and... it seems that this is only function iterating through series. and like you say if you return something truable then it will run 3 times... you can divide your procentage by 3 and you will get correct result.... but i'm not shure that this will be stable. they should have custom iterate or map function to modyfi your data if you need but i don't findy any. good luck man.:)  (just calc this from your data  in separate function)

Comment: Its just bugging me that why this is not working. What is wrong here !! /but yeah I guess a custom function for function calculation is the only answer or I need to monitor the names and make sure I don't consider them if they occur more than once. I'll trying using set to consider these values just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly noticed the `formatter` function may be called multiple times for the same pie slice. That is normal Highcharts behavior and it is sometimes needed for calculating position and anti-colision logic. As a solution, you can calculate the required value after chart creation, for example:

```
    var usageInAYear = 0;

    var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        ...,
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                ...,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        this.point.percentage = this.percentage;
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0) +
                            '%';
                    },

                }
            }
        }
    });

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
        if (point.name !== '> 1 year' && point.name !==
            'NOT USED') {
            usageInAYear += point.percentage;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("usage").innerHTML = Highcharts.numberFormat(usageInAYear, 0) + '%'
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4xwj3s2y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This helps to get the right result. Still would like to understand why formatter function get called multiple times? If I do not return anything then it's just called once. What changes with or without return?

Also any reason of writing `this.point.percentage = this.percentage;` inside the formatter function? The code works without this line as well.

Comment: Hi @Harshita Sethi, As I mentioned above, sometimes Highcharts has to recalculate data labels. If you don't return anything from the function, there are no data labels and additional calculations are not required. There is no information ine the API that the formatter is called only once for each data label. If you are more interested, you can add `debugger` in the formatter and check call stack. You are right, this line: `this.point.percentage = this.percentage;` is unnecessary.